# Не работает WiFi на Arcolinux (Arch)

Tags: wifi, archlinux

Поставил Arcolinux на ноутбук. Основан на Arch. Проводную сеть видит, WiFi не видит. Стандартные действия не помогли. Возможно проблема с драйвером или Network Manager.

**lspci -v**

```
0d:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8319
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 7
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at c4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 1.1.1.230  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 1.1.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4bb3:2530:745:c05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:0e:3c:f2:ed:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3170275  bytes 4727370631 (4.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 791039  bytes 62728736 (59.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 33  bytes 3710 (3.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33  bytes 3710 (3.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: ядро сами собирали или брали готовое? скорее всего нужно будет пересобрать и в списке устройств выбрать конкретно Вашу карточку. Потом, возможно, ещё firmware пакет установить и все будет.

Comment: Брал готовое. А что именно доставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коль вы уверены что у вас `RTL8723DE` и ноутбук `HP Notebook - 14-cm0007la`.
Эта команды установят драйвер на Wifi и Bluetooth:

```
sudo su
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b current
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

Comment: Ноутбук другой, ```HP Laptop 15-bs1xx```, но всё совместимо. Помогло, спасибо!